# mySQL load data local infile incorrect number format

Tags: mysql

I have an csv file formated like this,

```
sth, sth, "100,000,000", sth, "200,000"
sth, sth, "200,000,000", sth, "500,000"
```

When I used

```
mysql> load data local infile "thefile.csv" into table mytable terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminater by '\r\n';
```

then the numbers such as "100,000,000", "500,000" are truncated.

Please help me!

Comment: Truncated how? What kind of a field are you loading the data in?

Answer (score 3):

Remove spaces from the CSV-file:

```
sth,sth,"100,000,000",sth,"200,000"
sth,sth,"200,000,000",sth,"500,000"
```

And try to use this statement to load data -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'thefile.csv' INTO TABLE mytable
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(column1, column2, @var1, column4, @var2) -- specify actual field names
SET column3 = REPLACE(@var1, ',', ''), column5 = REPLACE(@var2, ',', ''); -- remove thousand separators
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach in php:

```
$in = fopen('filename.csv', 'r');
while (($row = fgetcsv($in, 10000, ',', '"')) !== false) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO ....");
}
fclose($in);
```

reference: [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work better than the OP's original code - seeing as the problem probably is the commas inside the numbers