# excel csv to mysql-numbers >1000 becomes 1.00

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

While uploading excel csv to mysql i find that '1000' becomes 1.00 and max value remains 999.99. While uploading same table with microsoft words spreadsheet it is fine but it has limitation of numbers of rows.how i can upload large table to mysql, i have csv data in .text files that has to be converted to .csv

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the thousand separator. Make sure that in your CSV, you see "1000" and not "1,000".

Also, see [mySQL load data local infile incorrect number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901149/mysql-load-data-local-infile-incorrect-number-format), it might help you out.

Comment: on my excel csv i see 1,000, how to deal with it?

Comment: The quick and dirty way would be to replace the commas by nothing in that column. There's also an example on how you can do it using the load data infile command in that link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either the formatting in your excel file or the limitations of numbers in your mysql table. Can you upload the file to google docs and show us the query which is used to create the table (alternatively - a screenshot of the table's structure)?